# Is it valid HTML to insert a hidden input between table rows?

Tags: html

Background: I am writing a Java app which auto generates a HTML table. As well as adding table rows, this app may insert hidden inputs. However, at present it simply inserts them into the table at the next opportunity, for example:

```
<table>
    <tr> ... </tr>
    <input type="hidden" />
    <tr> ... </tr>
</table>
```

So, my question: Is it valid HTML to insert a hidden input between rows like this, or is this likely to cause problems?

Comment: Why don't you run it through the W3C XHTML validator and find out? But i wouldn't think its valid.

Comment: Insert and check on http://validator.w3.org/ ...

Comment: Use validator at validator.w3.org and see for yourself

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's [not valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1).

```
<!ELEMENT TABLE - -
     (CAPTION?, (COL*|COLGROUP*), THEAD?, TFOOT?, TBODY+)>
```

Comment: Chosen for explanation why, but also love the answers pointing me to validator.w3.org; will never need to ask a HTML question again now.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not.

You should use the W3C validator and check by yourself your webpages : http://validator.w3.org/.

Answer (score 3):

It's not valid.

From http://validator.w3.org/

Line 9, Column 27: document type does not allow element "input" here

Answer (score 2):

It's not valid, after closing `</tr>` tag it can have only  `<tr>` or `</tbody>` or `</table>`. If you test it with w3c validator It will fail.